# Split a long string made of number-dot-number-space pattern separating the digit on left and on the right of the dot in bash

Tags: bash

I am reading a csv file with

```
dm=`awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}' file.csv`
```

I am keeping the first column, which looks something like:

```
25.3
26.3
27.3
```

for several rows.

I want a variable made up of

```
25 26 27
```

and one made up of

```
3 3 3
```

I am a total newbie in bash, but I am struggling how to make it... 
The closest thing to split I came up with is

```
echo $dm | tr "." " "
```

which is not sufficient at all...

Thanks,
 AB

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks, I know it sounds naive my question...but I really trying to do what is written there. I use few scripting languages, but bash is very challenging for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the output in an array `dm` and use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to 
remove a suffix and prefix pattern from the array values.

```
dm=( $(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}' file.csv) )
var1=${dm[@]%.*} # remove suffix `.*` -> "25 26 27"
var2=${dm[@]#*.} # remove prefix `*.` -> "3 3 3"
```

Comment: thanks. Since with your command all data is stored in one element, I also included `read -a var1b <<< $var1` to distribute the first element of the array `var1` having several blank separated values, into an array `var1b` where every element has a single value

Comment: You can use `var1=( ${dm[@]%.*} )` to assign the values to an array.